# How can I efficiently list all work item type states via ADO REST API?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to list all work item type states for an organisation (visible to the authenticated user) via REST API. It seemed more efficient to list all processes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/processes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) and then use the endpoint to list all work item types of those processes together with the states (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/work-item-types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP). However, I am missing some custom states in the response.

When I list all projects (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP), then all work item types of those projects (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-item-types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP) and then all states of those types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-item-type-states/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP), there is everything. But that is sooo many requests.

Can someone explain, why is the first approach not working? Every projet should be associated with a process. Or not? Do you know a better way to get all those states as efficiently as possible?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

As we can see from the official documentation : [Work Item Type States - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-item-type-states/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP#workitemstatecolor), it's in project level not the organization level. So, we need to get the states by project scope.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}/states?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

We can write a script to retrieve the projects and work item types in a loop, then get the states of each work item type.

**UPDATE:**

We can use [States - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/states/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP) REST API to return a list of all state definitions in a work item type of the process.

Below PowerShell script for your reference to return the states from a specific process:

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}", 
   [string]$processname = "Your-Process-Name",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get Process ID
$processesurl = "$orgurl/_apis/process/processes?api-version=6.0"
$processes = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $processesurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value | where {$_.name -eq $processname }
$processesid = $processes.id 

#List Work item types and witRefName 
$witsurl = "$orgurl/_apis/work/processes/$processesid/workitemtypes?api-version=6.0"
$witRefNames = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $witsurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value.referenceName #| where {$_.name -eq $processname }

#List WIT states
foreach ($witRefName in $witRefNames){
    $statesurl = "$orgurl/_apis/work/processes/$processesid/workItemTypes/$witRefName/states?api-version=6.0"
    $states = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $statesurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value.name 
   
    Write-Host "==================================================================================="
    Write-Host "$witRefName - States:" $states
    Write-Host "==================================================================================="
    echo `n 
}
```

[image]

If you want to retrieve all states from all processes, then you can get the processes and loop them in the script.

Comment: As I wrote in the question (see the links to the doc there), you can also retrieve work item types together with their states (expansion) by processes. However the results differ. Do you know, what kind of states is not returned via the process endpoint? Are there some, that are associated with a project but not with any process?

Comment: @JaroslavŠevčík Not sure about that (`retrieve work item types together with their states (expansion) by processes`), test that API, in some case it even cannot retrieve all the states (including system defined states) from a specific work item type. That should not be the correct API. I find the correct API to do that : [States - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/states/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP), please see the updated answer for details.